# How to avoid chain redirections using mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Basicly i'm working on my site to be SEO-friendly. I wanted to achieve following:

- Rewrite urls to pretty ones
- Remove multiple slashes (eg. `example.com/////something///` to `example.com/something/`
- Redirect www version to a non-www version.
- Hide index.php file from all urls
- Redirect from old (`/?id=something/` to new urls `/something/`)

I came up with this `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule .* $0 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([a-z0-9\/-]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1? [R=301]

RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$ /$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\/-]+)$ /?id=$1 [L]
```

...and though it's working it has a side effect: chain redirects, eg. `example.com/?id=something//////` -> `example.com/something//////` -> `example.com/something/`

So is there a way to rewrite or modify this code so it'll be redirecting just once to the preferred version of the url?

Comment: Start by adding **L** flag to all rewrite rules. Then, let us know what happens.

Comment: @felipe: I have added L flag to all, to any single one and changed order within those combinations and it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to interpret what you want, let's look at the rules in your question:

.1 Can't understand the purpose of this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule .* $0 [R=301]
```

.2 This rule-set in your question removes `www` and converts the query string `?id=val` to `/val`, but only when the incoming URI has `www` AND there is a query string as both conditions must be met:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([a-z0-9\/-]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1? [R=301]
```

.3 This rule

```
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$ /$1 [R=301]
```

Hides `index.php`, but only when it is in the root directory. Example:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?id=val
```

Does not work when it is in a subdirectory. Example:

```
http://www.example.com/folder/index.php?id=val
```

.4 Can't understand the purpose of this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\/-]+)$ /?id=$1 [L]
```

I suggest this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Redirects all www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Hides "index.php" keeping the query if present
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ $1/ [R=301,QSA,L]

#Converts query string `?id=val` to `/val`
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([^/]+)
RewriteRule .* /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember spiders will "adapt" to the correct new structure after a few months, and the problem may ultimately be a whole lot less severe than what it looks like initially. You can leave all the .htaccess code in place, knowing it always be there to correct any "old" references yet will in fact hardly ever actually be used.

I've never found an easy way to avoid multiple round trips back to the client when "fixing up" a URL to be in some sort of canonical form. mod_rewrite seems to be more focussed on the "local" redirect case where the client has no idea that the content it got back came out of a file structure that doesn't perfectly match that implied by the URL.

It is *possible* to save up all the URL mods locally, then provoke only one round trip to the client that delivers all the URL corrections all at once by setting everything in newly created "environment" variables then at the end asking basically "has anything changed?" However doing so is notably verbose and rather awkward and quite error-prone and has never become a "recommended technique".